# Network stream is not reading the last 8192 bytes of data, tripping out of the while loop

Tags: c#, tcplistener, networkstream

I'm reading a huge byte of around 3824726 bytes. I've tried a lot of functions for reading the whole bytes. It is reading exactly 3816534 bytes and the while loop is going away some where. Remaining 8192 bytes are not being read and also there is no exception. It reads till exactly 3816534 and then when on while loop goes away somewhere. Please some one help and tell what may be the problem here. I have tried a lot but the same thing is happening in different functions.

```
public static void ReadFully(NetworkStream stream, int initialLength)
    {
        if (initialLength < 1)
        {
            initialLength = 32768;            
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];           
        int chunk;
        try
        {                
            int read = -1;
            int totread = 0;

            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                totread += read;
                Console.WriteLine("Toatal Read" + totread);
                string filePath = "C:\\Foo.txt";
                StreamWriter objWriter;
                using (objWriter = File.AppendText(filePath))
                {
                    objWriter.WriteLine(totread);
                    objWriter.Flush();
                    objWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Toatal Read" + totread);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
    }
```

Client Side Sending bytes to server

```
byte[] fileA;


        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("IpAddress");
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipAd.ToString(), Port);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample        Pictures/06250_2.jpg");
        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:/Users/703132799/Desktop/Foo.txt");
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        fileA = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int length = 0;
        length = fileA.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Buffer Length-" + length);
        stream.Write(fileA, 0, fileA.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Whole code at server, It is Asynchronous way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartServer();            
    }

    private static TcpListener _listener;
    public static void StartServer()
    {

        IPAddress localIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("IPAddress");
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, Port);
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
        _listener.Start();
        WaitForClientConnect();
    }

    private static void WaitForClientConnect()
    {
        object obj = new object();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new System.AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), obj);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            clientSocket = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyn);
            HandleClientRequest clientReq = new HandleClientRequest(clientSocket);
            clientReq.StartClient();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        WaitForClientConnect();
    }
}

public class HandleClientRequest
{
    TcpClient _clientSocket;
    NetworkStream _networkStream = null;

    public HandleClientRequest(TcpClient clientConnected)
    {
        this._clientSocket = clientConnected;
    }

    public void StartClient()
    {
        _networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
        WaitForRequest();
    }

    public void WaitForRequest()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

        _networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ReadCallback, buffer);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string sRecMsgAsciiWithHex = string.Empty;
        NetworkStream networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
        ReadFully(networkStream, 65536);
    }

    public static void ReadFully(NetworkStream stream, int initialLength)
    {
        if (initialLength < 1)
        {
            initialLength = 32768;            
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];           
        int chunk;
        try
        {                
            int read = -1;
            int totread = 0;
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Foo.txt"))
            {

                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    totread += read;
                    Console.WriteLine("Toatal Read" + totread);
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    //string filePath = "C:\\Foo.txt";
                    //StreamWriter objWriter;
                    //using (objWriter = File.AppendText(filePath))
                    //{
                    //    objWriter.WriteLine(totread);
                    //    objWriter.Flush();
                    //    objWriter.Close();
                    //}
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Toatal Read" + totread);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { throw; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the root issue - but it might be worth a shot - it's very wrong to open file for write each time you recieve a buffer of bytes; also binary file should be written binary. Use using(var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath)) { before while and write to fileStream directly via fileStream.Write - no need to flush and close - using statement will take care about it.

Comment: Also - why are you catching the exception, and throwing it again? First off, a 'rethrow' would be better (you can see where it was thrown from) - and secondly, if you are just going to throw it with no further processing, why bother catching it in the first place?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Thanks for the quick response. Actually, I wanted to know why it is tripping out for the last set of bytes. In the client application I'm converting a image into bytes and getting it here. Why exactly at 3816534 it is going away somewhere without any exception. it is not reading the last 8192 bytes of data.

Comment: @user1805948 - if you 1) debugged it and 2) you're sure that socket is done before last read I suggest examining server code - can you post it here as well.

Comment: @ScottEarle Thanks for the point u said. It was worthable. But why it is not reading the last set of bytes. I'm very surprised to see the behaviour of the program for different functions too. It stops exactly at the same point for reading the data.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar The thing i've posted here is server code and this readfully method I'm calling in a readcall back, i.e. asynchronously.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar Do u want to see the whole code of server side?

Comment: @user1805948 - the relevant parts (sending to network stream)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I've posted the client side code where we are converting an image into bytes and sending it to the server.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar I've also posted the whole server side code. please see to it.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar So sending using streams,sends data in chunks. Right?

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar Can u please explain what the below code is doing. We are reading the file from the specifeid location and sending it. But why in parts?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You're not closing the connection - simple as that; if you're interested I can post a full code sample.

Put `client.Close();` after the `stream.Flush()` in the end of "Client Side Sending bytes to server" routine.

All the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      StartServer();

      // test sending
      Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4000);
      // get a file here instead
      byte[] longBuffer = new byte[3824726];
      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
      // emulated stream over emulated buffer
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream(longBuffer, false)) {
        while (true) {
          int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
          if (read <= 0) {
            break;
          }
          for (int sendBytes = 0; sendBytes < read; sendBytes += client.Send(buffer, sendBytes, read - sendBytes, SocketFlags.None)) {
          }
        }
      }
      // the tricky part ;)
      client.Close();
      Console.In.ReadLine();
      _stop = true;
    }

    private static TcpListener _listener;
    private static volatile bool _stop = false;

    private sealed class Client : IDisposable {
      public Socket Socket { get; private set; }
      public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }
      public FileStream WriteStream { get; private set; }

      public Client(Socket socket) {
        if (socket == null) {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");
        }
        Socket = socket;
        Buffer = new byte[4096];
        WriteStream = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\foo" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".txt");
      }

      public void Close() {
        if (Socket != null) {
          Socket.Close();
        }
        if (WriteStream != null) {
          WriteStream.Close();
        }

      }

      public void Dispose() {
        Close();
      }
    }

    public static void StartServer() {
      IPAddress localIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
      IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 4000);
      _listener = new TcpListener(ipLocal);
      _listener.Start();
      _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(BeginAcceptSocketCallback, null);
    }

    private static void BeginAcceptSocketCallback(IAsyncResult asyn) {
      Client client = null;
      try {
        client = new Client(_listener.EndAcceptSocket(asyn));
        client.Socket.BeginReceive(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, BeginReceiveCallback, client);
      } catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginAcceptSocketCallback failure", false);
      } catch (SocketException e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginAcceptSocketCallback failure", false);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginAcceptSocketCallback failure", true);
      }
      if (!_stop) {
        _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(BeginAcceptSocketCallback, null);
      }
    }

    private static void BeginReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
      var client = (Client)result.AsyncState;
      try {
        int bytesRead = client.Socket.EndReceive(result);
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
          client.WriteStream.Write(client.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          client.Socket.BeginReceive(client.Buffer, 0, client.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, BeginReceiveCallback, client);
        } else {
          client.Close();
        }
      } catch (SocketException e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginReceiveCallback failure", false);
      } catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginReceiveCallback failure", false);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        HandleSocketFailure(client, e, "BeginReceiveCallback failure", true);
      }
    }

    private static void HandleSocketFailure(Client client, Exception exception, string message, bool isFatal) {
      // log exception as well at least for isFatal = true
      if (client != null) {
        client.Close();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: So sending using streams,sends data in chunks. Right?

Comment: Can u please explain what the above code is doing. We are reading the file from the specifeid location and sending it. But why in parts?

Comment: using streams fro sending the data, I'm sending-4047810 bytes but at the server side only- 4039618 bytes are being recieved and after that going away from the while loop.

Comment: The code u have posted above is totally for sending the bytes to the server right?

Comment: It is now not going out of the loop but reading only 3816534 bytes. But we have sent a total of 3824726 bytes. Is it a problem or is it correct?

Comment: It is now not going out of the loop but reading only 3816534 bytes. But we have sent a total of 3824726 bytes. Is it a problem or is it correct?

Comment: @user1805948 - the example is for both server/client in one - it doesn't happen to me in example - it does read exactly 3824726 bytes and create file of 3824726 bytes in c:\foo--.txt.

Comment: I cant change my server program to ur server code as it needs many changes in rest of the project. Can u please check my code and tell me where the problem is or where I have to hange for reading all the bytes.

Comment: U have used BeginAcceptSocketCallback and BeginReceiveCallback which has different mechanism than my code. Please see my code and test it.